starting with negative slack variable
considered the flow LP problem: max $z=2x+y$
subject to $x+y\le 6$ and
$x+y\ge 1 $ so the standard form is $x+y+e_1=6$ and $-x-y+ e_2=-1$ (or $x+y-e_2=1$).
Starting with an infeasible solution, $e_1=6$ and $e_2=−1$, the regular simplex method still converges to the optimal solution $x=6$  and $y=0$. My question is: what issues arise from starting with an infeasible solution? What is the purpose of the two-phase simplex method in this context? Is the example above a special case?"​

Welcome to OR.SE. I don't understand your question well, but the primal simplex starts from a feasible basic solution and, keeping this feasibility, tries to prove optimality. Vice versa, the dual simplex method can start from an infeasible solution and, keeping the optimality, try to reach a feasible solution. Also, the second constraint, $x+y\geq 1$, in the standard form can be written as $x+y+R-s = 1$, and this is why we need to use an appropriate $BigM$ on the artificial variable $R$ to get a ride from infeasibility. Is it what you are looking for?
